# TSQL One sequence of characters must follow another

Tags: t-sql, case

First time question but thought I would see if anyone has a clear idea how to do this. Thank you.

I have a view that contains information about procedures in a hospital. Usual name and date fields and then there is a field that contains all the associated procedures that are concatenated into a single field and pipe delimited. Procedure codes are usually 4 digits and represent each individual procedure completed.

E.g. Name, DateOfBirth,|W822|W833|Z846|Z942|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

Procedure codes starting W833,W834,W835 should always be followed by a site code (where on the body the proc was carried out) Z00-Z93 or Z95-Z99

However,  it may have a Y code in between (Y282,...) the W and the Z code

There may also be a Z94* following the Y* code

How could you construct a query to find incorrect procedures.

I assume the best way would be a rather convoluted CASE statement. Anyone have any other suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Please try to set up a [mcve], at least provide a set of sample data with the expected output. Furthermore, it helps to show, what you've tried yourself.

Comment: Hi @distressednhs is there any chance of splitting that data structure in to 2 tables? One with the patient information and one with the procedure information? Then you can store each patient and procedure as a row rather than having concatenated columns which encourage complex case statements.

Comment: Best option is not to use delimited strings in the first place....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get rows where the procedure codes are in the wrong order you could use a function to validate your procedure codes:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_ValidateOrder ( @InputString NVARCHAR(MAX), @Delimiter NCHAR(1))
RETURNS BIT 
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Valid BIT = 0, @Errors INT
    /* Table to hold splitt string */
    DECLARE @T TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1),Val NVARCHAR(128) NULL)
    INSERT INTO @T
        SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@InputString,@Delimiter) WHERE value != ''
    /* Validated order */
    ;WITH rn AS (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY val) AS rn
            ,id,
            val
        FROM @T 
    )
    /* Count errors */
    SELECT @Errors=SUM(CASE WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM rn WHERE id!=rn
    /* Set return value */
    IF @Errors>0
        SET @Valid=0
    ELSE
        SET @Valid=1

    RETURN @Valid
END
```

I used the following test data to validate:

```
/* Test Data*/
DECLARE @data TABLE (DateOfBirth VARCHAR(6),ProcedureCode VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @data (DateOfBirth,ProcedureCode)
VALUES ('010176','|W822|W833|Z846|Z942|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||'),
('120176','|W822|Z282|W833|Z846|Z942|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||')

/* Validated test data */
SELECT
    DateOfBirth,
    dbo.fn_ValidateOrder(ProcedureCode,'|') AS ValidOrder,
    ProcedureCode
FROM @data
WHERE dbo.fn_ValidateOrder(ProcedureCode,'|') = 0
```

Note that this will only work on SQL 2016 and newer, as the function use SPLIT_STRING.

Comment: Thank you MariusE. Will try to digest this when I get time and apply it. Looks very promising.